# Firestore query to populate data with list of IDs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking to make the most efficient query with firestore that would populate a list of favorite articles and get the relevant data that is represented by the articleId and authorId.
For example, let's say we have a favorites list composed of articles. The favorites list looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: '123',
    userId: '456'
    articleId: '789',
    authorId: '101'
  }
]
```

Would it be quicker to make a query that would first query the favorites list, then query an articles list from an array of articleIds and finally query an authors list from an array of authorIds? (So 3 queries total):

```
const snapshot = await firestore
  .collection('favorites')
  .where('userId', '==', userId)
  .orderBy('created')
  .get();
const favorites = [];
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  const favorite = doc.data();
  favorites.push(favorite);
});

const articleIds = favorites.map(favorite => favorite.articleId)
const articlesSnapshot = await firestore
  .collection('articles')
  .where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', articleIds)
  .get();
const articles = [];
articlesSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
  const article = doc.data();
  articles.push(article);
});

const authorIds = favorites.map(favorite => favorite.authorId)
const authorsSnapshot = await firestore
  .collection('users')
  .where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', authorIds)
  .get();
const authors = [];
authorsSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
  const author = doc.data();
  authors.push(author);
});

return { authors, articles, favorites }
```

Or should I iterate through the list of favorites and make individual queries to get the individual article (from the articleId) and individual author (from the authorId)?

I feel like the second option would be way slower because of all the individual queries made.. Am I right? Would the first query be more efficient (faster)?

Comment: Generally speaking, the performance of Firestore is based on the number of documents you read.  So if you read the same number of documents in both cases, the performance difference would be negligible.  But this is something you could pretty easily benchmark, so you should just do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite important what Doug wrote in the comment so I decided to make wiki answer:

> Generally speaking, the performance of Firestore is based on the
> number of documents you read. So if you read the same number of
> documents in both cases, the performance difference would be
> negligible. But this is something you could pretty easily benchmark,
> so you should just do that instead.

From my side, I can add, that concept you are using is relational, while you are using NoSQL database. So you might think of different non-relational data structure which will fit your purposes.  I think it's too broad to give any advises having information provided in the question, as it does not give general concept how the data will be used and what is the scale of system.

Comment: The relational model works best for me at the moment.. I might refactor it if I notice a big drop in performance at some point, but for now it's still quite fast.. I just wanted to know which was the preferable way of making this particular query with firestore. Doug answered my question by letting me know that it was the number of documents you read that really matters..